# Always update on duplicate when using save() in custom model

Tags: mysql, model, magento-1.9, resource-model

I have a custom model linked to a custom table. In that table, the column sku is unique. I'd like the following code to *always* update on duplicate:

```
Mage::getModel('company/product_log')
  ->setData('sku', 'abc123')
  ->setData('error', 'Invalid price.')
  ->save();
```

I'd like to do this from within the model itself instead of having to repeat update-vs-insert logic everywhere I want to use this table.

What is the best way to do this, or an existing example already in Magento?

Comment: since you know the sku you want to update, why you dont load the product by it's sku and then call save() on that?

Comment: I second @kostaskostarelo. Why do you want to record the duplicate SKU insert attempt? Unless that duplicate-SKU operation is precisely what you're looking for, you should simply check if the SKU exist in the `product_log` table, and save the model accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method that I came up which seems to work fine is to add this method to my model:

```
/**
 * @param $sku
 * @return $this|Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
public function loadBySku($sku) {
    $matches = $this->getResourceCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('sku', $sku);

    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        return $this->load($match->getId());
    }

    return $this->setData('sku', $sku);
}
```

So instead of this:

```
Mage::getModel('company/product_log')
  ->setData('sku', 'abc123')
  ->setData('error', 'Invalid price.')
  ->save();
```

I now do this:

```
Mage::getModel('company/product_log')
  ->loadBySku('abc123')
  ->setData('error', 'Invalid price.')
  ->save();
```

If a row exists with that SKU, it will be loaded, altered and saved. If a row doesn't exist with that SKU, the blank model will have it's SKU set, and then have the error set and the row saved.

`loadBySku()` could be altered to include more default values when it can't load an existing row by SKU.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you need without reinventing the wheel:

```
Mage::getModel('company/product_log')
  ->load('abc123', 'sku')
  ->setData('error', 'Invalid price.')
  ->save();
```

->load() method inherited from Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract

1. The load will control the unserialization of fields
2. Performs 1 SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Fot example look at app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php how works saving of order_status_history.

```
public function addStatusHistoryComment($comment, $status = false)
{
    ...
    $history = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')
        ->setStatus($status)
        ->setComment($comment)
        ->setEntityName($this->_historyEntityName);
    $this->addStatusHistory($history);
    return $history;
}
```

or look at Enterprise_Logging

```
    return Mage::getSingleton('enterprise_logging/event')->setData(array(
        'ip'         => Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr(),
        'user'       => $username,
        'user_id'    => $userId,
        'is_success' => $success,
        'fullaction' => "{$request->getRouteName()}_{$request->getControllerName()}_{$request->getActionName()}",
        'event_code' => $eventCode,
        'action'     => 'login',
    ))->save();
```